# ¿Cómo alinear el botón a la altura de los input del formulario?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

os explico, tengo lo que seguramente sera un problema bastante simple, pero que no le encuentro las solucion.
Tengo el siguiente codigo asi

```css
.row {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}
.col7 {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

.border_right {
border-right: 1px solid;
-moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% , #000000 100%);
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #ffffff  0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% ,  #000000 100%);
border-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% , #000000 100%);
border-image-slice: 1;
font-family: 'serif';
}

.footer-title h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1em;
}

.formular {
    margin: 2em 0em 0 2em;
}

.f-form {
    margin: 1em 0em 1em 2em;

}

.form-title {
    float: left;
    width: 59%;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.form-title h2 {
    margin: 1em;
    color: #5aa8c4;
}

.cont-section {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#contact .block1, .block2, .block3 {
    margin:0em 0em 2em 0em;
}

#contact h3 {
    color: #5aa8c4;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#contact p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#contact a {
    color: black;
 }

.contactform input {
    padding: 0.8em 0em 0.8em 2em;
    width: 81%;
 }

.contactform label {
    margin-left: 1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
 }

.contactform select {
    padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 86%;
    background: white;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    border: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1em;
 }

.contactform p {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}


.wpcf7-submit {
    width: 30% !important;
    background-color: #3c95b8;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
}

.wpcf7-textarea {
    width: 85%;
}

.wpcf7-form-control {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.wpp-list li {
    list-style: inside square;
}

.wpcf7 input[type="submit"] {

}
```

```html
 <div class="col7">
                            <div>
                                <div class="contactform row border_right">
<div class="formular">
                                        <h2>Kontaktformular</h2>
                    <div class="f-form"><div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f59-o1" dir="ltr" lang="de-DE">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/test/fitnesspedia_neu/wp-content/themes/fitnesspedia/query_handler.php#wpcf7-f59-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input name="_wpcf7" value="59" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9.1" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_locale" value="de_DE" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f59-o1" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" type="hidden">
</div>
<p><label> Betreff / Thema:*<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap Betreff"><input name="Betreff" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span> </label></p>
<p><label> <strong>Ihre Nachricht:*</strong><br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap textarea-200"><textarea name="textarea-200" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Meine Nachricht enthält:* (bitte auswählen)<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-682"><select name="menu-682" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Verbesserungsvorschlag">Verbesserungsvorschlag</option><option value="Infos">Infos</option></select></span></label></p>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap nameUser"><input name="nameUser" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap adresse"><input name="adresse" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Adresse" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap plz"><input name="plz" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="PLZ, Stadt" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap telefon"><input name="telefon" value="Telefon" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input name="email" value="Email" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span></p>
<p><input value="Abschicken" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit"></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div></div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

Y lo que quiero es que el boton de envio quede justo debajo de el de email, pero a la derecha. Pero no encuentro la solucion, por que cuando disminuyo la pantalla se rueda bastante.
Aquì os dejo un enlace a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Saggi/qumdacqa/)
Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero sea lo que buscas saludos

```css
.row {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}
.col7 {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

.border_right {
border-right: 1px solid;
-moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% , #000000 100%);
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #ffffff  0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% ,  #000000 100%);
border-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% , #000000 100%);
border-image-slice: 1;
font-family: 'serif';
}

.footer-title h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1em;
}

.formular {
  padding:40px; /*codigo nuevo*/
}
/*nuevo codigo*/
*{
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*nuevo codigo*/
.f-form {
    width:100%;/*codigo nuevo*/

}

.form-title {
    float: left;
    width: 59%;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.form-title h2 {
    margin: 1em;
    color: #5aa8c4;
}

.cont-section {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#contact .block1, .block2, .block3 {
    margin:0em 0em 2em 0em;
}

#contact h3 {
    color: #5aa8c4;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#contact p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#contact a {
    color: black;
 }

.contactform input {
    padding: 0.8em 0em 0.8em 2em;
    width: 100%;/*codigo nuevo*/
 }

.contactform label {
width:100%;/*codigo nuevo*/
    margin-left: 1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
 }

.contactform select {
    padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;/*codigo nuevo*/
    background: white;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    border: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1em;
 }

.contactform p {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
   width: calc(100% - 20px);/*codigo nuevo*/
  margin: 10px;/*codigo nuevo*/
}
/*codigo nuevo*/
.contactform p.con-btn {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
/*codigo nuevo*/
.wpcf7-submit {
    width: 30% !important;
    background-color: #3c95b8;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
}

.wpcf7-textarea {
    width:100%;
}

.wpcf7-form-control {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.wpp-list li {
    list-style: inside square;
}

.wpcf7 input[type="submit"] {

}
```

```html
<div class="col7">
                            <div>
                                <div class="contactform row border_right">
<div class="formular">
                                        <h2>Kontaktformular</h2>
                    <div class="f-form"><div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f59-o1" dir="ltr" lang="de-DE">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/test/fitnesspedia_neu/wp-content/themes/fitnesspedia/query_handler.php#wpcf7-f59-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input name="_wpcf7" value="59" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9.1" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_locale" value="de_DE" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f59-o1" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" type="hidden">
</div>
<p><label> Betreff / Thema:*<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap Betreff"><input name="Betreff" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span> </label></p>
<p><label> <strong>Ihre Nachricht:*</strong><br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap textarea-200"><textarea name="textarea-200" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Meine Nachricht enthält:* (bitte auswählen)<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-682"><select name="menu-682" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Verbesserungsvorschlag">Verbesserungsvorschlag</option><option value="Infos">Infos</option></select></span></label></p>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap nameUser"><input name="nameUser" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap adresse"><input name="adresse" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Adresse" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap plz"><input name="plz" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="PLZ, Stadt" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap telefon"><input name="telefon" value="Telefon" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input name="email" value="Email" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span></p>

<!-- agrego classe al contenedor p -->
<p class="con-btn"><input value="Abschicken" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit"></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div></div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias......perdon haber tardado tanto...he estado malo.

Comment: si te soluciona tu problema por favor dale como respuesta correcta para ayudar a los que tengan un problema similar en la comunidad

Comment: Perdon, me despiste. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero podrías definir un ancho del form, luego darle `100%` al ancho de los elementos del formulario y agregar `box-sizing: border-box` a estos. Sería algo así:

```
.wpcf7-form {
  width: 80%;
}

.contactform input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}

.wpcf7-form p:last-of-type {
  text-align: right
}
```

Al final agrego un `text-align: right` al párrafo que contiene el submit button, podrías customizar ese selector desde la entrada del form en Wordpress y evitar el `last-of-type` ;)

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en el tema, pero creo que si lo que usas es el Framework Bootstrap se resuelve con un pull-left...al menos asi me ha funcionado las pocas veces que he intentado modificar la posición del botón de envio en FormContact.
Saludos

Comment: ¿podrías colocar un ejemplo del código para resolverlo mediante un ejemplo? asi quien busque la pregunta entenderá como resolverlo de manera aplicada. Echale un vistazo a [answer]

Comment: Utilizo Wordpress. Edito el tema y dejo un enlace a un editor externo.

Answer (score 0):

Como todos tus `input` encima del botón están englobados dentro de un párrafo y tienen un 81% de anchura (con respecto a dicho párrafo), tendrás que englobar también tu botón dentro de ese párrafo para poder obtener la misma anchura (81% respecto al párrafo).

Como no quieres que el botón ocupe la totalidad de la anchura (81% del párrafo) yo he englobado tu botón dentro de un `span` asignándole `display: block` para que pueda coger anchura ya que al ser el `span` un elemento inline, no puede tener anchura. Una vez hecho esto, le he asignado el mismo `padding` que le habías asignado a tus `input`.

Por último, he alineado el botón a la derecha con la propiedad `text-align: right` para alinearlo a la derecha. Esto se produce ya que el botón (que en realidad es un `input`) es un elemento inline y lo puedes alinear dentro de la misma línea.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
.row {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;

}
.col7 {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }

.border_right {
border-right: 1px solid;
-moz-border-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% , #000000 100%);
-webkit-border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( #ffffff  0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% ,  #000000 100%);
border-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff 0%,#ffffff  11%, #5aa8c4 12%, #5aa8c4 47% , #000000 100%);
border-image-slice: 1;
font-family: 'serif';
}

.footer-title h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1em;
}

.formular {
    margin: 2em 0em 0 2em;
}

.f-form {
    margin: 1em 0em 1em 2em;

}

.form-title {
    float: left;
    width: 59%;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.form-title h2 {
    margin: 1em;
    color: #5aa8c4;
}

.cont-section {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#contact .block1, .block2, .block3 {
    margin:0em 0em 2em 0em;
}

#contact h3 {
    color: #5aa8c4;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

#contact p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#contact a {
    color: black;
 }

.contactform input {
    padding: 0.8em 0em 0.8em 2em;
    width: 81%;
 }

.contactform label {
    margin-left: 1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
 }

.contactform select {
    padding: 0.5em 2em 0.5em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 86%;
    background: white;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    background: linear-gradient(white, #d1d1d1 30%);
    border: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1em;
 }

.contactform p {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}


.wpcf7-submit {
    width: 30% !important;
    background-color: #3c95b8;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
}

.wpcf7-textarea {
    width: 85%;
}

.wpcf7-form-control {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.wpp-list li {
    list-style: inside square;
}

.wpcf7 input[type="submit"] {

}


/* ************** NUEVO ***************** */
#submit{
  display: block;
  padding: 0.8em 0em 0.8em 2em;       
  width: 81%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="col7">
                            <div>
                                <div class="contactform row border_right">
<div class="formular">
                                        <h2>Kontaktformular</h2>
                    <div class="f-form"><div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f59-o1" dir="ltr" lang="de-DE">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/test/fitnesspedia_neu/wp-content/themes/fitnesspedia/query_handler.php#wpcf7-f59-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input name="_wpcf7" value="59" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9.1" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_locale" value="de_DE" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f59-o1" type="hidden">
<input name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" type="hidden">
</div>
<p><label> Betreff / Thema:*<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap Betreff"><input name="Betreff" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span> </label></p>
<p><label> <strong>Ihre Nachricht:*</strong><br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap textarea-200"><textarea name="textarea-200" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span> </label></p>
<p><label> Meine Nachricht enthält:* (bitte auswählen)<br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-682"><select name="menu-682" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Verbesserungsvorschlag">Verbesserungsvorschlag</option><option value="Infos">Infos</option></select></span></label></p>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap nameUser"><input name="nameUser" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap adresse"><input name="adresse" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Adresse" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap plz"><input name="plz" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="PLZ, Stadt" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap telefon"><input name="telefon" value="Telefon" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span><br>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input name="email" value="Email" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span>
<span id="submit"><input value="Abschicken" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit"></span></p>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form></div></div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

todos los cambios que hice estan dentro del div id="wpcf7-f59-o1", si no entendi mal querías que el botón quede a la derecha del final del email, en mi caso le di un tamaño maximo al div contenedor, a su vez le indiqué a los input que tomen el tomaño máximo del div y por finalizar le dije al boton que se vaya al final y a la derecha del div contenedor.

No toqué para nada el archivo de estilos, sólo agregué los comandos css que me parecieron útiles al finalizar cada input y el div contenedor.

espero que te sirva.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="col7">
        <div>
            <div class="contactform row border_right">
                <div class="formular">
                    <h2>Kontaktformular</h2>

                    <!-- A este div le indiqué un tamaño máximo de 20% -->
                    <div class="f-form">
                        <div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f59-o1" dir="ltr"
                            lang="de-DE" style="width: 20%">
                            <div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
                            <form
                                action="/test/fitnesspedia_neu/wp-content/themes/fitnesspedia/query_handler.php#wpcf7-f59-o1"
                                method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                                <div style="display: none;">
                                    <input name="_wpcf7" value="59" type="hidden"> <input
                                        name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9.1" type="hidden"> <input
                                        name="_wpcf7_locale" value="de_DE" type="hidden"> <input
                                        name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f59-o1" type="hidden">
                                    <input name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0" type="hidden">
                                </div>
                                <p>
                                    <label> Betreff / Thema:*<br> <span
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap Betreff"><input
                                            name="Betreff" value="" size="40"
                                            class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required"
                                            aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="text"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <label> <strong>Ihre Nachricht:*</strong><br> <span
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap textarea-200"><textarea
                                                name="textarea-200" cols="40" rows="10"
                                                class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required"
                                                aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea></span>
                                    </label>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <label> Meine Nachricht enthält:* (bitte auswählen)<br>
                                        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-682"><select
                                            name="menu-682"
                                            class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required"
                                            aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"><option
                                                    value="Verbesserungsvorschlag">Verbesserungsvorschlag</option>
                                                <option value="Infos">Infos</option></select></span></label>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <!-- Acá estan los cambios, en cada input agregué 100% el tamaño del input contenido dentro del div, a su vez achiqué el tamaño del DIV correspondiente, y al finalizar le indiqué al botón que se mantenga a la derecha con el float:left, osea siempre va a quedar a la derecha del tamaño total del div que en este caso le puse un porcentaje de la pantalla -->
                                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap nameUser"><input
                                        name="nameUser" value="" size="40"
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"
                                        placeholder="Name" type="text" style="width: 100%"></span><br>
                                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap adresse"><input
                                        name="adresse" value="" size="40"
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"
                                        placeholder="Adresse" type="text" style="width: 100%"></span><br>
                                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap plz"><input
                                        name="plz" value="" size="40"
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"
                                        placeholder="PLZ, Stadt" type="text" style="width: 100%"></span><br>
                                    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap telefon"><input
                                        name="telefon" value="Telefon" size="40"
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"
                                        type="text" style="width: 100%"></span><br> <span
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input
                                        name="email" value="Email" size="40"
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false"
                                        type="text" style="width: 100%"></span>
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                <!-- A este botón le indiqué que se vaya  a la derecha del contenedor máximo -->
                                    <input value="Abschicken"
                                        class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" type="submit"
                                        style="float: right;">
                                </p>
                                <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @dario-b Ahí te mandé te una respuesta que creo te puede llevar a servir, copia y pega donde trabajes, abrazos.